# How can I select all values of a multi dimensional tensor based on a mask with PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor `pred`, which has a `.size()` of `[4, 53, 161]`. I have another tensor `mask`, which has a `.size()` of `[4, 53]`.

The `mask` is only 0's and 1's. What I want to do is get the values of `pred` where `mask` has a value of `1`. You'll notice that `pred` has one more dimension than `mask`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mask = mask.unsqueeze(2)
new_pred = pred * mask
```

That will add extra dimension. It will be now `[4, 53, 1]`. Rest will be taken care of the broadcasting. (if you do some operation)

Suppose you have a tensor of shape`[4, 53, 164]` and now you want to reduce it to `[4, 53]` then you can apply arithmetic operations like this `new_pred.mean(2)`.

Comment: How do I get pred to only have the values that have a `1` in `mask`?

Comment: @Shamoon.: Just multiply.

Comment: I don't want pred to have zeroes in all the `mask == 0` spots. I want to reduce the dimension of `pred`

Comment: @Shamoon.: Check now

Comment: @Shamoon.; Sorry? Cheeck what you asked

Comment: I basically want to do `pred[x:y]` somehow, where `mask[x:y]` is 1. But it might not be continuous.

Comment: @Shamoon.: If you do the above code...you will get exactly that thing. `new_pred` is same dim as `pred`

Comment: I need `new_pred` to be a smaller dimension

Comment: @Shamoon.: Well think of it like this - you need to drop a dimension of `pred` based on some criteria? Well that you can do later `new_pred.mean(2)`

Comment: @Shamoon.: Check once again the answer.